# android parallel API requests with retrofit and coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I have multiple API requests that need to be called in parallel, the sequence doesn't matter.
What really matters is that all the calls should be requested to implement the UI.
The problem is that sometimes some requests don't get called which returns null values, in other words, NO GUARANTEE THAT ALL THE REQUESTS WILL BE CALLED.
I have read a lot about parallel API requests and launchers but still don't know what I have missed or what I did wrong.

here is my view model class that has all functions

```
@HiltViewModel
class MatchDetailsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val api:FootballApi,
    val app: Application,
): AndroidViewModel(app) {
    private val _matchDetailsMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<ResponseState<FixtureById>>()
    private val _matchStatsMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<ResponseState<Stats>>()
    private val _matchLineupsMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<ResponseState<Lineups>>()
    private val _matchBenchMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<ResponseState<Bench>>()
    private val _matchSideLinesMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<ResponseState<SideLine>>()
    private val _matchStandingsMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<ResponseState<Standings>>()
    val matchStandingsLiveData: LiveData<ResponseState<Standings>> = _matchStandingsMutableLiveData
    val matchSideLinesLiveData: LiveData<ResponseState<SideLine>> = _matchSideLinesMutableLiveData
    val matchStatsLiveData: LiveData<ResponseState<Stats>> = _matchStatsMutableLiveData
    val matchDetailsLiveData: LiveData<ResponseState<FixtureById>> = _matchDetailsMutableLiveData
    val matchLineupsLiveData: LiveData<ResponseState<Lineups>> = _matchLineupsMutableLiveData
    val matchBenchLiveData: LiveData<ResponseState<Bench>> = _matchBenchMutableLiveData


fun callAll() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val getMatchDetailsCall = async { getMatchDetails(1582601) }
        val getMatchStatsCall = async { getMatchStats(1582601) }
        val getMatchLineupsCall = async { getMatchLineups(1582601) }
        val getMatchBenchCall = async { getMatchBench(1582601) }
        val getMatchSideLineCall = async { getMatchSideLine(15006543) }
        val getMatchStandingsCall = async { getMatchStandings(12880) }
        try {
            getMatchDetailsCall.await()
            getMatchStatsCall.await()
            getMatchLineupsCall.await()
            getMatchBenchCall.await()
            getMatchSideLineCall.await()
            getMatchStandingsCall.await()
        }
        catch (_: Exception){}
    }
}

suspend fun getMatchStandings(seasonId: Int) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    _matchStandingsMutableLiveData.postValue(ResponseState.Loading())
    try {
        val response = api.getMatchStandings(seasonId = seasonId)
        Log.i("getMatchStanding()", response.body().toString())
        _matchStandingsMutableLiveData.postValue(ResponseState.Success(response.body()!!))
    }
    catch (exception: Exception) {
        Log.e("getMatchStanding()", exception.toString())
    }
}

suspend fun getMatchSideLine(id: Int) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    _matchSideLinesMutableLiveData.postValue(ResponseState.Loading())
    try {
        val response = api.getMatchSideLines(id = id)
        Log.i("getMatchSideline()", response.body().toString())
        _matchSideLinesMutableLiveData.postValue(ResponseState.Success(response.body()!!))
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        Log.e("getMatchSideline()", exception.toString())
    }
}

fun getMatchDetails(id: Int) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    _matchDetailsMutableLiveData.postValue(ResponseState.Loading())
    try {
        val response = api.getMatchDetails(id = id)
        Log.i("getMatchDetails()", response.body().toString())
        _matchDetailsMutableLiveData.postValue(ResponseState.Success(response.body()!!))
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        Log.e("getMatchDetails()", exception.toString())
    }
}

suspend fun getMatchStats(id: Int) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    _matchStatsMutableLiveData.postValue(ResponseState.Loading())
    try {
        val response = api.getMatchStats(id = id)
        Log.i("getMatchStats()", response.body().toString())
        _matchStatsMutableLiveData.postValue(ResponseState.Success(response.body()!!))
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        Log.e("getMatchStats()", exception.toString())
    }
}

suspend fun getMatchLineups(id: Int = 6) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    _matchLineupsMutableLiveData.postValue(ResponseState.Loading())
    try {
        val response = api.getMatchLineups(id = id)
        Log.i("getMatchLineups()", response.body().toString())
        _matchLineupsMutableLiveData.postValue(ResponseState.Success(response.body()!!))
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        Log.e("getMatchLineups()", exception.toString())
       
    }
}

suspend fun getMatchBench(id: Int) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    _matchBenchMutableLiveData.postValue(ResponseState.Loading())
    try {
        val response = api.getMatchBench(id = id)
        Log.i("getMatchBench()", response.body().toString())
        _matchBenchMutableLiveData.postValue(ResponseState.Success(response.body()!!))
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        Log.e("getMatchBench()", exception.toString())
    }
}
}
```

And here's my call in activity class

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        matchDetailsViewModel.callAll()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `callAll()` method like this:

```
fun callAll() {
   getMatchDetails(1582601) 
   getMatchStats(1582601)
   getMatchLineups(1582601)
   getMatchBench(1582601)
   getMatchSideLine(15006543)
   getMatchStandings(12880)
}
```

And delete the `suspend` keyword from each method.